# Jenkins Deploy Error Tomcat 6.x

Tags: maven, deployment, jenkins

Im trying to use jenkins to build and deploy the war file to a tomcat present in different server and im getting the following error -

```
Deploying /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ura_Web/workspace/ura-1.0.war to container Tomcat 6.x Remote
ERROR: Publisher hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher aborted due to exception
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to redeploy [/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ura_Web/workspace/ura-1.0.war]
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:195)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:64)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:90)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:905)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:878)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:47)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:36)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:804)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:776)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:969)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:726)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1618)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:491)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:247)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://192.168.2.X/manager/list
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1401)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:504)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.list(TomcatManager.java:622)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.getStatus(TomcatManager.java:635)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:176)
... 16 more </code>
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Could you please tell us more about `java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://192.168.2.X/manager/list`? Is it wrong ip address?

Comment: its 104 instead of X but stackoverflow was not allowing ips as it was my first post.

Comment: Do you have Tomcat manager deployed?

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly this problem just now and still have not solved it. However, I suspect it is happening because of proxy issues.

Is it possible to try setting the manager URL to `http://localhost`
rather than `http://192.168.2.X`? This worked for me, showing that the credentials were at least correct and the module functions. When I switch the manager URL back to a remote machine or the FQDN of the local server, it again failed. This indicates to me something proxy related.

The only trouble then is configuring the proxy settings for Jenkins, especially `http.nonProxyHosts`. If you can do that maybe you'll have more luck than me. I cannot get the Jenkins System Information proxy values to change no matter what I do!

Also manually test from a browser on both the build server and elsewhere your access to the manager URL: `http://192.168.2.X/manager/list`

Comment: You are right.. this is something to do with my proxies. I am trying to use scp plugin instead of deploy, it worked!